# Example about finitely generated module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a problem with my lesson about generated module: Find a family $\{M_\alpha\}_\Delta$ of R-modules each of which is finitely generated but $\oplus_\Delta M_\alpha$ is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like $\oplus _{i=1}^\infty F$ for a field $F$, as an $F$-module?

Each $M_\alpha=F$ is a cyclic $F$ module, and the sum of infinitely many is not finitely generated.

Comment: it is just a direct product of R-modules $M_\alpha$

Comment: @Hoàng I don't understand your comment. There isn't any direct product mentioned in your question or mine... This example appears to suit your requirements.

Comment: sorry because of my bad so i dont understand your comment before edited. so is there an example with $\Delta$ is finite?

Comment: @Hoàng No, in that case, the sum is obviously generated by the union of the generators of the finitely many $M_\alpha$.

Comment: okay i understand it, thank you for answer ^^